The difference of type of value result in dev tool


var jobs = [
    'Real Estate',
    'Urban Planning',
    'QA Engineer',
    'Full Stack Developer',
    'BA'
];


Array.prototype.forEach2 = function (callback) {
    for (var i in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            callback(this[i], i, this)
        };
    };
};

var a = jobs.forEach2(function (job, index) {
    console.log(index, typeof job)
});

var b = jobs.forEach(function (cv, index) {
    console.log(index, typeof cv)
});



I'm struggling with the difference of the result of method typeof in Javascript.
I have tried to define a forEach() array method for practicing my callback function. However the result of this typeof is different.
So What is the difference of the result of typeof show in dev tool between 'string' with the red color and string with the black color?
This is the result shows in dev-tools
This is my syntax
I have tried to turn the index into the type of number by using parseInt(i) and the result is same. However, I'm curious about the difference between two result of typeof string.
Thank you so much for your help
I really want to know the difference of the result of typeof method when it shows 'string' with red color vs string with black color

Please include your code in the post itself using a snippet or code block, not screenshots. Also this seems more like a console difference than an actual "problem", as both are strings with the word string in them, they just get displayed slightly differently.

Sorry it's the first time I do this work. I edited it

The result by using snippet is not different between 2 method however I don't know why it's different in my browser (chrome) - (in screenshot)

Indeed! I think I once figured out what triggers a browser to write such difference, but consider that both have to be strings in order to be output by the browser like this, so chalk it up to a rendering quirk of the console I presume. Might be the difference between a raw string and a string string (like how raw strings also display newlines as \n while regular strings just print the newline directly - there is a difference but usually we dont notice it - and we dont tend to generally consider either different from the other).

index is a string in forEach2 and console.log's first parameter is a format string which explicitly controls the output through special symbols like %o %s and so on, which is why it disables the built-in formatting heuristics of devtools.
